# Calculating leaves of full m-ary trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know the formula for leaves when vertices $n$ is known is:

$$
\frac{(m-1)n+1}{m} 
$$

I am trying to solve the problem how many leaves does a full 3-ary tree with 100 vertices have?

this gives

$$\frac{{(3-1)100}+1}{3} = \frac{(2{}\cdot{}100)+1}{3} = \frac{201}{3} = 67.$$

that's your answer.

Comment: Isn't there 3 leaves for each vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it's an arithmetic error: you should take $\frac{(3-1)\cdot 100 + 1}{3} = \frac{2\cdot 100 + 1}{3} = \frac{201}{3} = 67$, not $\frac{202}{3}$.

But in actual cases when the answer is not an integer, that means it's impossible to have a full $m$-ary tree with that many vertices.

For instance, to consider small examples: you can have a full $3$-ary tree with $4$ vertices and $3$ leaves: just the root, and three children. If you take one of the leaves and give it $3$ children, you get a full $3$-ary tree with $7$ vertices and $5$ leaves. Any intermediate number of vertices - $5$ or $6$ - is impossible.